# Hosting on Azure web app with xhprof

Tags: 8

We are trying to host Drupal 8 at Azure web app, but developers is complaining on performance problems. As solution to mitigate it, they suggested to install xhprof. In order to install it, we've downgraded to PHP 5.5.9, but could not login to Drupal now; it just returns a 500 error. PHP error log is clean, IIS says that there is a CGI error (something wrong in PHP handler); since there is no access to Drupal, we could not check errors there.
Can you help us in setting Drupal 8 with XHProf on Azure web app and figure out what the problem is?